# Ubuntu Update Error util-linux

Tags: updates

I am attempting to update my box and I keep getting this error and the machine refuses to update.  I keep getting the same 4 updates within the GUI that are either failing or stuck in some way.  Any recommendations will be appreciated.

```
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: error processing package util-linux (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
Errors were encountered while processing:
 util-linux
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```